# C#. Не получается десериализовать json, выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        var request = new RestRequest(url);
        var response = client.Get(request);
        var weatherResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(response.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(Resp.current.temp_c);
        foreach(var e in Resp.forecast.forecastDay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.day.daily_chance_of_rain);
        }
        
    }
}

public class Root
{
    public Forecast forecast { get; set; }
    public Current current { get; set; }
    public double wind_kph { get; set; }
    public string wind_dir { get; set; }
    public double pressure_mb { get; set; }
    public double uv { get; set; }
}

public class Current
{
    public double temp_c { get; set; }
}

public class Forecast
{
    public List<ForecastDay> forecastDay { get; set; }
}
public class ForecastDay
{
    public Day day { get; set; }
    public Astro astro { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public double daily_chance_of_rain { get; set; }
}

public class Astro
{
    public string sunrise { get; set; }
    public string sunset { get; set; }
}
```

Forecast.forecastDay.get вернул null. При выполнении выдает ошибку. Пытался к gpt обращаться, лучше не стало.
Пример Json

```
{
"current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1680967800,
        "last_updated": "2023-04-08 16:30",
        "temp_c": 15.0,
        "temp_f": 59.0,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Sunny",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png",
            "code": 1000
        },
        "wind_mph": 9.4,
        "wind_kph": 15.1,
        "wind_degree": 70,
        "wind_dir": "ENE",
        "pressure_mb": 1025.0,
        "pressure_in": 30.27,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 41,
        "cloud": 0,
        "feelslike_c": 14.5,
        "feelslike_f": 58.1,
        "vis_km": 10.0,
        "vis_miles": 6.0,
        "uv": 4.0,
        "gust_mph": 7.8,
        "gust_kph": 12.6
    },
    "forecast": {
        "forecastday": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-04-08",
                    "date_epoch": 1680912000,
                    "day": {
                        "maxtemp_c": 14.6,
                        "maxtemp_f": 58.3,
                        "mintemp_c": 5.4,
                        "mintemp_f": 41.7,
                        "avgtemp_c": 9.9,
                        "avgtemp_f": 49.8,
                        "maxwind_mph": 6.9,
                        "maxwind_kph": 11.2,
                        "totalprecip_mm": 0.0,
                        "totalprecip_in": 0.0,
                        "totalsnow_cm": 0.0,
                        "avgvis_km": 10.0,
                        "avgvis_miles": 6.0,
                        "avghumidity": 70.0,
                        "daily_will_it_rain": 0,
                        "daily_chance_of_rain": 0,
                        "daily_will_it_snow": 0,
                        "daily_chance_of_snow": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "uv": 3.0
                    },
                    "astro": {
                        "sunrise": "06:21 AM",
                        "sunset": "07:45 PM",
                        "moonrise": "10:56 PM",
                        "moonset": "07:08 AM",
                        "moon_phase": "Waning Gibbous",
                    "moon_illumination": "96",
                    "is_moon_up": 1,
                    "is_sun_up": 0
                 }
     }
     ]
}
```

Мог в json со скобками накосячить